# How reliable is Android Download Manager?

Tags: android, download, android-download-manager

We have an app which uses Android system Download Manager to download some important files. The problem is not all devices in the production are able to download the file successfully.

Upon checking, I found

1. Download Manager can be disabled in pre lollipop devices. This will not initiate download on any files.
2. Download Manager can be force stopped. Then the download goes to pending state and resumes after some time.
3. Download Manager CLEAR DATA. This will erase the download Ids stored in Download Manager DB. So any query to download manager with the particular download Id will return cursor empty.

With all these, Is it still good to depend on Android Download Manager.

Is anybody facing similar issues here?

Also what can be the possible alternative? Using In-app download manager using HttpUrlConnection is another idea I can think of.

Comment: What is it that you want to download and store ? Images, videos, pdf, docs, keys ?

Comment: Im downloading .apk file. As it is critical I don't prefer to miss this download

Answer (score 0):

Use [Android Asynchronous Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/).

Example code:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.get("https://example.com/file.png", new FileAsyncHttpResponseHandler(/* Context */ this) {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, File response) {
        // Do something with the file `response`
    }
});
```

See the [FileAsyncHttpResponseHandler Javadoc](https://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/FileAsyncHttpResponseHandler.html) for more information.